# Using the "IN" operator in WHERE clause somehow reverses the order from a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, string, left-join, sql-order-by

The following is part of a mysql query that I'm using to retreive price rules for a product on an ecommerce website I'm working on:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(pr.price,',',pr.special,',',pr.sort_order,',',pr.quantity) SEPARATOR ';') AS price_rules 

FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ppr.product_id, ppr.price, ppr.special, ppr.sort_order, ppr.quantity
    FROM products_price_rules ppr
    ORDER BY ppr.special DESC, ppr.quantity ASC, ppr.sort_order ASC
) pr ON pr.product_id = p.id

LEFT JOIN products_to_categories cat ON p.id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN products_to_websites ptw ON p.id = ptw.id

WHERE p.status = 1 AND p.id = 277
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 1
```

This returns the following array, which is correct:

Array([0] => Array([price_rules] => 3.80,1,1,1;5.00,0,0,1 ))

However, when I change the query a bit and add the IN operator in the WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(pr.price,',',pr.special,',',pr.sort_order,',',pr.quantity) SEPARATOR ';') AS price_rules 

FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ppr.product_id, ppr.price, ppr.special, ppr.sort_order, ppr.quantity
    FROM products_price_rules ppr
    ORDER BY ppr.special ASC, ppr.quantity DESC, ppr.sort_order DESC
) pr ON pr.product_id = p.id

LEFT JOIN products_to_categories cat ON p.id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN products_to_websites ptw ON p.id = ptw.id 

WHERE p.status = 1 AND cat.category_id IN (77)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING ( FIND_IN_SET(1, GROUP_CONCAT(pr.special)) )
LIMIT 1
```

It returns the following:

Array([0] => Array([price_rules] => 5.00,0,0,1;3.80,1,1,1 ))

The order of the data is reversed somehow. When I change the ORDER BY clause in the subquery to "ppr.special DESC, ppr.quantity ASC, ppr.sort_order ASC" (DESC instead of ASC and vice versa), it returns the data like the first example.

Why does this happen and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `ORDER BY` *within* `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    pr.price, ',', pr.special, ',', pr.sort_order,',',pr.quantity
    ORDER BY ppr.special DESC, ppr.quantity, ppr.sort_order
    SEPARATOR ';'
) AS price_rules
```

Note that there is no need to `CONCAT()` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`: it does it by default already.

Looking at the rest of your query, it seems like it could probably be optimized in several ways. For example:

- `DISTINCT` appears multiple times, which is usually not necessary
- the `WHERE` predicate on the `LEFT JOIN`ed table turns the operation to an `INNER JOIN`
- `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` does not produce a consistent result

If you were to ask another question, providing sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic, one might be able to suggest optimizations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to work! I didn't know you could use ORDER BY withing GROUP_CONCAT. Changed the query and it's giving me the correct results now.